# подсветка синтаксиса и подсказки YII2 для Visual Studio Code

Tags: yii2, visual-studio-code

При написании каких-либо классов, функций и т.д. YII2 в VScode, редактор ругается на ошибки в коде и красит в красный цвет, меня это напрягает. Может кто-нибудь знает плагин (или что то вроде этого), который научит VScode работать с юишкой и заодно включит подсказки для фреймворка.

открыть весь проект в редакторе не вариант, потому что работаю на сервере удаленно по ftp

[image: ошибки синтаксиса]

Comment: Если вы открываете отдельные файлы с FTP, то подсветку синтаксиса сделать не получится.